# Buscar coordenadas en X Km a la redonda

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito ayuda con esta **SELECT**:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'[', 
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', h.hotel_id , 'nom', h.nom, 'estrelles', h.categoria, 'puntuacio', h.puntacio, 'tipus', h.tipus, 'descripcio', h.descripcio, 'adreca', h.adreca, 'lat', h.latitud, 'lng', h.longitud, 'web', h.web )),
']'
) 
FROM hotels h ;`
```

Consulta que dado un punto (lat y long) nos dé qué restaurantes / hoteles están disponibles en 'X' Km a la redonda en From JSON pudiéndolo utilizar en la variable lugares del html index.html

[image: Esttos son los campos de la Tabla Hoteles..[![Aqui los datos que contiene..]

[image: Propiedades de las variables de los campos]

Comment: Puedes añadir información sobre la tabla? sobre lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Te puse una respuesta que espero que te ayude, podrías aplicarlo cambiando algunas cosillas, o eso, o puedes añadir información sobre lo que saldría.

Comment: @Aritzbn la SELECT que pusiste:
Seria algo asi..
`SELECT h.nom, h.latitud, h.longitud
FROM hotels h
WHERE  h.latitud < 40.4167754 + 1   
AND h.latitud > 40.4167754 - 1`

Comment: latitud i latitud ??

porque he hecho un ejemplo de poner Madrid.. i un 1 KM i me sales los hoteles de Barcelona..

Comment: @MohamedA.B la terminé borrando, lo que puse era algo muy simplificado, no creo que te valiese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con algo del tipo

```
SELECT h.nom, h.latitud, h.longitud 
FROM hotels h 
WHERE h.latitud between (40.4167754 + x) and (40.4167754 - x) 
AND h.longitud between (40.4167754 +y) and (40.416775 -y)
```

Siendo `X` el **rango en km** pasados a la **respectiva equivalencia en latitud**

y siendo `Y` el **rango en km** pasados a la **respectiva equivalencia en longitud**

Creo esto te podría dar un resultado aproximado, pero no sería 100% exacto.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de como funcionan el tema de las cordenadas pero....
Creo recordad a latitud puede variar entre -90 y +90 y la longitud entre -180 y +180(o al revés, no estoy seguro cual era cual), que sucede si estoy buscando hoteles a 200km a la redonda?